# to check location service enable or not in android device

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

sorry for asking this but i am not a developer for android app. i wanted to ask if a custom geolocation android app can be coded in such a way that when user launch the app and detect that the device's location service is off, it will show up as a prompt or the app will not proceed further until location service is on manually by the user?

we are using mobile device management (mdm) to manage android mobile device but the mdm did not has the ability to enforce location service settings.

the custom geolocation android app requires the location service to enable to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether GPS is enabled or not and display a message if it is not enabled

```
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            //here do what you want when the GPS service is enabled

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "is enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder locationDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this);
            locationDialog.setTitle("Attention");
            locationDialog.setMessage("Location settings must be enabled from the settings to use the application");
            locationDialog.setCancelable(false);
            locationDialog.setPositiveButton("Open settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            locationDialog.create().show();
        }

    }
}
```